# Server to Server Authentication in wso2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am very new to wso2 API manager. Sometimes an application might need to call a service in another application on behalf of a user. How can we make this in wso2 API manager by configuring Signed JWT Authenticator as like Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server?

Comment: @JimiLoe I improved upon your Suggested Edit, please take a look at what [additional edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28693223/revisions) should have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is authenticated by saml2 in the application, then application can get the oauth token using saml token and invoke the apis on behalf of user.
check following links for more detail

1.http://shafreenanfar.blogspot.in/2014/02/exchanging-sml2-token-to-oauth2-token.html

2.http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.in/2014/01/invoking-apis-using-web-app-with-oauth2.html